# How does one retrieve a Notification to update it?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

So, whenever someone creates a Post, I want others notified. Hence, I send out a Notification.

I know the logistics of setting the number with `setNumber(int num)`, and how to create an `InboxStyle` to display multiple posts.

The problem is if a new notification comes in, it has no knowledge of whether or not another notification exists. I can't just request that Notification by its notification_id that I assigned it and then append a String with `addLine(String string)`, nor can I update the number of posts with the setNumber method above. I'm new to creating Notifications and I've been reading about InboxStyle, using it, but every guide leaves out how to keep in sync with if that notification is still up, and how to update it. They brush that off as a trivial matter.

Yes, I understand a Notification can be updated via the `NotificationManager.notify(int, notification)` method, but unless you recreate what the new notification will look like, it simply overwrites your current notification.

Is there something I'm missing or not understanding about how to simply update notifications?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be trying to "keep in sync with if that notification is still up". Your `Notification` should reflect the contents of your data model, and it should be updated when the data model changes.

For example, suppose you are writing an email client. You want a `Notification` for unread messages. When there are no unread messages, you have no `Notification`. When your background logic retrieves new messages, you update your data store to reflect those messages, and you call some `heyLetTheUserKnowBoutDemEmails()` method. That method queries the data store, finds out how many unseen messages there are, and calls `notify()` on `NotificationManager` to post a suitable `Notification`, using `setNumber()`, `addLine()`, and so forth, based on what is in the data store. Whether or not there happens to already be a `Notification`, for some previous `heyLetTheUserKnowBoutDemEmails()` call, is immaterial. When the user responds to the `Notification`, or otherwise opens up the inbox, your UI would then update the data store to mark the messages as seen (i.e., no longer need to be notified about) and clears the `Notification`. Lather, rinse, repeat.

So, it's not so much that it is a "trivial matter", but that:

- It is merely a matter of replacing the existing `Notification`, and
- The rules for when you should replace the existing `Notification` are almost completely dependent upon your app and its business rules, which are outside the scope of Android documentation and many blog posts, Stack Overflow answers, and the like.

Comment: Unless I were to ping the server for this information, the solution above would require a local datastore. I think pinging the server for the data is a bit drastic, and having a local datastore for this seems like quite the commitment for the impression of updating a Notification. Is there a way to know when if the Notification with a certain notification_id was viewed/canceled? If so, it might make sense to store the info in a SharedPreference.

Comment: @David: "Is there a way to know when if the Notification with a certain notification_id was viewed/canceled?" -- use [`setDeleteIntent()` on your `NotificationCompat.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setDeleteIntent%28android.app.PendingIntent%29).